# Android Studio fails to start - Cannot register font

Tags: windows-8, fonts, android-studio

I've just downloaded the latest Android Studio (v0.1.1) and installed it, however the program will not run.

I am running on Windows 8, 64 bit.
I have added both the environment variables (JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME).

When running studio.bat through a command prompt (with administer privileges), it outputs this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin>studio.bat
ERROR: Cannot register font: /fonts/Inconsolata.ttf
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.registerFont(AppUIUtil.java:129)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.registerBundledFonts(AppUIUtil.java:120)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Cannot register font: /fonts/Inconsolata.tt
f
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.jav
a:55)
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:65)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.registerFont(AppUIUtil.java:137)
        at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.registerBundledFonts(AppUIUtil.java:120)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:48)
        ... 6 more
```

To try and fix the problem I have downloaded the Inconsolatta.tff file from Google and installed it myself, as well as placed the file in the directory where the bat file is looking for it (it wasn't there originally... odd), however to no avail.

Can anyone explain what I need to do to get this working? I quite like Android Studio!

BTW, on previous install attempts, if I ran the program at the end of it's install, it loaded up, but then any attempt after closing it it did not work, if that helps...